# Hacer una alerta en la cual no se pueda modificar los campos de un crud

Tags: php

Buenas noches
Estaba haciendo un ejercicio donde hay un formulario de baja alta y modificacion para clientes y facturas.Mi duda empezo ya que al no poder relacionar tablas mediante phpmyadmin (usando el paquete wamp) , ya que me dice un mensaje de que no admite relaciones , decidi en vez de que el alerta aparezca a la hora de tratar de eliminar un cliente que tenia facturas pendientes(como dice el ejercico) , lo cambie para que aparezca si quiero eliminar una direccion en concreto.Entonces sabiendo eso , queria saber si este codigo estaria bien`

```html
$Direc=$_GET["Direc"];
 
$conexion->query("DELETE FROM cliente WHERE Direccion='$Direc'");
if($Direc="estoesloquenopuedepir"){ 
echo'<script type="text/javascript">
        alert("Tarea Guardada");
        window.location.href="index.php";
        </script>';
}
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En mysql las tablas deben ser innodb para poder relacionarlas, las tablas myisan no soportan relaciones, en phpmyadmin si es posible realizar las relaciones si ambas tablas son innodb.

Respecto a lo que preguntas.

Antes de ejecutar el delete del cliente realiza una consulta en la tabla facturas para verificar si el cliente tiene alguna factura. si obtienes resultados imprime el mensaje y no continúes con la ejecución del programa.

Comment: Con un for y un else podria ser por ejemplo?

Comment: prueba usando una subconsulta para validar la relacion.  DELETE FROM cliente WHERE Direccion='$Direc' and id_cliente not in (SELECT id_cliente from facturas where facturas.id_cliente = cliente.id_cliente)

Answer (score 0):

para poder relacionar tablas en mysql puedes utilizar mysqlworbech y luego trasladar la base a tu phpmyadmin estableciendo conexion o generando un query.

pero el alerta que esta realizando esta correctamente programada

Comment: Muchas gracias leonardo , donde estaria ubicado ese workbench?

Comment: mi estimado descargue por medio de este link https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/5.2.html y realizara el diseño de la base de datos